# Get the Selected Tree View Item

Tags: c#, wpf

I am using a wpf tree in a .net form. So, I don't have any xaml. I simply do everything in code. I am using Hierarchical Data Template to bind my data to the wpftree.

I am trying to find a way to get the TreeViewItem for the Node selected in the tree. I tried registering a EventHandler on the SelectedItemChanged event on the TreeView, but in that handler I only get the associated data object. Since my tree is virtual, ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem doesn't work.

When I searched on StackOverflow, one suggestion was to listen to the TreeViewItem.Selected event. 
But I couldn't find a way to do this in code. ( I don't have a xaml).

Any help is greatly appreciated.

thank you.

Comment: Why don't you have XAML?

Comment: `So, I don't have any xaml. I simply do everything in code` - Wrong. **Don't create or manipulate UI elements in procedural code in WPF. That's what XAML is for.** - If people gave me $0.01 every time I need to say this I'd be richer than Microsoft by now.

Comment: Hi, I am pretty new to wpf. I am under the impression that I cannot have a xaml when I embed wpf controls in a .net form ...am I wrong?

Comment: Maybe because he's using an [`ElementHost`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.integration.elementhost(v=vs.110).aspx) and creates the TreeView programmatically. Anyway: You should take a look at [this article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742215(v=vs.110).aspx). They create a XAML control that demonstrates how to send data back to the Windows Form.

Comment: Hi Chris, you are correct. I am using ElementHost to create the TreeView Programatically. thank you for the link

Comment: Also: I am not sure what you are meaning with "my tree is virtual". In C#, a `virtual` variable is something, that can be overwritten by a derived class with `override`.

Comment: @ChrisK -By virtual, I am enabling Virtualization on the TreeView using the VirtualizationStackPanel.  System.Windows.Controls.VirtualizingStackPanel.SetIsVirtualizing(m_wpfTree, true);

Answer (score 0):

What you could do is attach the handler to each control every time you add it

```
void AddTreeViewItem()
{
    TreeView t = new TreeView();
    TreeViewItem treeItem = new TreeViewItem();
    t.Items.Add(treeItem);

    treeItem.Selected += DoSomethingHere;
}

private void DoSomethingHere(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Tree Item Selected");
}
```

Comment: I am not directly adding the TreeViewItems in my code... I am only doing the data binding.